# pandas DataFrame: how to sentence into words and select rows that have more than 10 words?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with each row a sentence. However the sentences are not the same length. I want to select those rows which contains more than 10 words, something like

```
df = df.loc[len(df[src].str.split()) > 10]
```

But this will raise the Error of Key being True. How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with [`series.str.len()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df[df['src'].str.split().str.len() > 10]
```

Comment: @YingqiangGao Instead of saying "Thanks", if the answer helped you, upvote and/or mark it as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).